# Airflow won't manage to find GCP credential json file

Tags: python-3.x, docker, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I am to run a DAG that downloads .parquet file and copy it into a gcp storage bucket.

The upload task fails due to the following error:

```
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: File /.google/credentials/google_credentials.json was not found.
```

For some context:

- I am running Airflow on Docker ([docker compose file](https://github.com/DataTalksClub/data-engineering-zoomcamp/blob/main/week_2_data_ingestion/airflow/docker-compose.yaml))
- All the composition is running on Ubunto VM via GCP compute engine
- This is the DAG code:

```
    import os
    import logging
    from datetime import datetime
    
    
    from airflow import DAG
    from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
    from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
    
    from google.cloud import storage
    from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryCreateExternalTableOperator
    
    PROJECT_ID = os.environ.get("GCP_PROJECT_ID")
    BUCKET = os.environ.get("GCP_GCS_BUCKET")
    
    FILE_DATE = '2022-10'
    FILE_NAME = f'yellow_tripdata_{FILE_DATE}.parquet'
    XCOM_FILE_NAME = f'yellow_tripdata_{FILE_DATE}'
    SOURCE_URL = 'https://d37ci6vzurychx.cloudfront.net/trip-data/'
    URL_TEMPLATE = SOURCE_URL + FILE_NAME
    

    PATH_TO_LOCAL_HOME = os.environ.get("AIRFLOW_HOME", "/opt/airflow/")
    
   
    def upload_to_gcs(bucket, object_name, local_file):

        storage.blob._MAX_MULTIPART_SIZE = 5 * 1024 * 1024 
        storage.blob._DEFAULT_CHUNKSIZE = 5 * 1024 * 1024 
    
        client = storage.Client()
        bucket = client.bucket(bucket)
    
        blob = bucket.blob(object_name)
        blob.upload_from_filename(local_file)
        
    
    default_args = {
        "owner": "airflow",
        "start_date": datetime(2019, 1, 1),
        "depends_on_past": False,
        "retries": 1,
    }
    
    with DAG(
        dag_id="ingest_yellowtaxi_to_CGP",
        schedule_interval="0 6 2 * *",
        default_args=default_args,
        catchup=False,
        max_active_runs=1,
        tags=['dtc-de-hw-task'],
    ) as dag:
    
        download_datafile_task = BashOperator(
            task_id="download_datafile_task",
            bash_command=f"curl -sSLf {URL_TEMPLATE} > {PATH_TO_LOCAL_HOME}/{FILE_NAME}"
        )
    
    
        local_to_gcs_task = PythonOperator(
            task_id="local_to_gcs_task",
            python_callable=upload_to_gcs,
            op_kwargs={
                "bucket": BUCKET,
                "object_name": f"raw/{FILE_NAME}",
                "local_file": f"{PATH_TO_LOCAL_HOME}/{FILE_NAME}",
            },
        )
    
        delete_data_file = BashOperator(
            task_id="delete_data_file",
            bash_command=f"cd {PATH_TO_LOCAL_HOME} && rm {FILE_NAME}"
        )
    
    download_datafile_task >> local_to_gcs_task >> delete_data_file
```

the authentication json is inside the .google/credentials directory on the VM:

[image]

and to the best of my know the volume mounting and env setting are correct.

Yet Airflow could not find the file.

I tried a few solution that didn't yield any success:

- Changed the volume mounting to indicate explicitly the path and the json file name
- ran `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<path/filename.json>` and `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` (looks like that this command dosen't override the docker-compose settings as I create the task that check the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable and it still /.google/credentials/google_credentials.json)
- Tried to find `/.google/credentials` directory on Airflow worker but couldn't
- Tried to bypass that by setting a Airflow GCP connection ([using this guide](https://junjiejiang94.medium.com/get-started-with-airflow-google-cloud-platform-docker-a21c46e0f797)) on the UI but keep getting bad request error

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step try to rename the file in the container by replacing the mounting path by `~/.google/credentials/<filename.json>:/.google/credentials/google_credentials.json:ro`, then create an Airflow connection by adding the following env var (replace `<your google project name>` by the project name):

```
export AIRFLOW_CONN_GOOGLE_CLOUD_DEFAULT='google-cloud-platform://?key_path=%2F.google%2Fcredentialsgoogle_credentials.json&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform&project=<your google project name>&num_retries=5'
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution @hussein, now it finds the file...but I get this error:

`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.google/credentials/google_credentials.json`

It is a progress already...

Comment: can you try on your host VM to execute `chmod 774 ~/.google/credentials/<filename.json>`?

Comment: Wow! that works...finally....
I really appreciate your help, as I have tired to solve this for at least 10 hours...
Have a good year mate!